# Python - Evenly divide numbers in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, divide

How can, efficiently, a number be evenly distributed in 'n' groups?

I thought of this function, but it doesn't divide completely evenly this numbers.

```
def DivideList(total_num, div_num):

    div = int(total_num)/int(div_num)

    if (div_num < total_num):
        div_list = [[div*i, div*(i+1)] for i in range(div_num)]
        div_list[div_num-1][1] = total_num
    else:
        div_list = [[i, i+1] for i in range(total_num)]

    return div_list

print DivideList(100, 8)
```

Could this also be achieved with list comprehension?

EDIT:

Example:

`DivideList(20, 4) >> [[0, 5], [5, 10], [10, 15], [15, 20]]`

`DivideList(14, 4) >> [[0, 4], [4, 8], [8, 11], [11, 14]]`

Comment: Please post your desired results

Comment: Please also mention the sample example of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Have you considered using numpy.linspace ? It can generate numbers in a regular fashion using parameters similar to what you are looking for. More info here:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html

Comment: so are you simply trying to force a float? `div = 1.0*total_num/div_num`

Comment: Your examples don't make sense: are the steps the same or not? In the last example, you step `4` 2 times and then `3` 2 times, but you never mention that requirement.

Comment: @Dandekar That's the key of this problem: not using float numbers as each number in here represents a file index

Comment: @brianpck My bad if I didn't explained more in depth. Those "sublists" represent intervals of files to be procesed. The first number is the first file to process, and the second number, the file where to stop processing (thus the last file won't be processed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example1:

```
def DivideList(total_num, div_num):
    div = total_num / div_num
    left = total_num - div * div_num
    result = []
    m = 0
    for i in xrange(left):
        k = m
        m += (div + 1)
        result.append([k, m])

    for i in xrange(div_num - left):
        k = m
        m += div
        result.append([k, m])

    return result
```

More concise：

```
def DivideList(total_num, div_num):
    div = total_num / div_num
    left = total_num - div * div_num
    result = []
    for i in xrange(0, left*(div+1), div+1):
        result.append([i, i+div+1])

    for i in xrange(left*(div+1), total_num, div):
        result.append([i, i+div])

    return result
```

Example2:
Here's a generator that yields the chunks you want:

```
def DivideList(total_num, div_num):
    div = total_num / div_num
    left = total_num - div * div_num
    m = 0
    for i in xrange(left):
        k = m
        m += (div + 1)
        yield [k, m]

    for i in xrange(div_num - left):
        k = m
        m += div
        yield [k, m]
```

More concise：

```
def DivideList(total_num, div_num):
    div = total_num / div_num
    left = total_num - div * div_num
    for i in xrange(0, left*(div+1), div+1):
        yield [i, i+div+1]

    for i in xrange(left*(div+1), total_num, div):
        yield [i, i+div]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility for achieving the result. Please specify the corner cases you wish to handle, if this is not sufficient. For instance, it does not make sense to cast to `int` if the expected arguments are already `int`s, as in your example.

As suggested by ma3oun, `np.linspace` is an excellent way to achieve this:

```
>>> def divide_list(total_num, div_num):
...     temp = np.linspace(0, total_num, div_num + 1)
...     return list(zip(temp[:-1], temp[1:]))
...
>>> divide_list(100, 8)
[(0.0, 12.5), (12.5, 25.0), (25.0, 37.5), (37.5, 50.0), (50.0, 62.5), (62.5, 75.0), (75.0, 87.5), (87.5, 100.0)]
```

This produces even steps, unlike your last example:

```
>>> divide_list(20, 4)
[(0.0, 5.0), (5.0, 10.0), (10.0, 15.0), (15.0, 20.0)]
>>> divide_list(14, 4)
[(0.0, 3.5), (3.5, 7.0), (7.0, 10.5), (10.5, 14.0)]
```

My previous example using `np.arange`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> def divide_list(total_num, div_num):
...     div = total_num / div_num
...     temp = np.arange(0, total_num + div, div)
...     return list(zip(temp[:-1], temp[1:]))
...
>>> divide_list(100, 8)
[(0.0, 12.5), (12.5, 25.0), (25.0, 37.5), (37.5, 50.0), (50.0, 62.5), (62.5, 75.0), (75.0, 87.5), (87.5, 100.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Old suggestion:**

> So if you are simply trying to force a float division,
>   change your code as
>
> ```
> div = 1.0*total_num/div_num
> ```

**EDIT**: So I am still unclear on your requirement, but my attempt is below. Also, does it have to be list comprehensions? really affects readability in this case. I managed to implement it in two list comprehensions.

```
def Segments(total_num,div_num):
    return [(total_num/div_num)+1 if(i<total_num%div_num) else (total_num/div_num) for i in range(div_num)]

def DivideList(series):
    return [[sum(series[0:i]),sum(series[0:i+1])] for i in range(len(series))]

print DivideList(Segments(100,8))
```

Maybe someone can shorten/beautify this further.